# Is normal Kryptonian physiology affected by magic?

Tags: dc, superman

To make myself clear, I'm aware that one of Superman's major weaknesses is magic, but is that because he's also superpowered by a yellow sun, or just because he's from Krypton? Would Kryptonians be as susceptible to magic under a red sun?

Comment: It's not that Superman has some specific weakness to magic, it's that he has no protection from it. Superman is just as susceptible as any regular human (or presumably Kryptonian) would be.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica As I mentioned in my answer below, "_No_ special defense" is debatable; Clark's natural toughness and higher energy content in his body would make it difficult for most conceivable magic attacks which use pure "force" to harm him. True, he _is_ susceptible to the supernatural like any "mortal", but unless specially crafted for him, he's been shown to be stronger and more durable than most mortals dealing with magic.

Comment: @Russhiro indeed, but the question seems to assume that he's *more* vulnerable to magic than a normal person.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica _Exactly_ my point. The assumption is that "somehow, him having powers makes him **more** vulnerable to magic than us." To a degree, the post from Bjorn Erikson seems to reinforce that.  However, the practical examples I offered seem to canonically indicate _otherwise;_ while he has no "special" defense against it, his _natural defenses_ **still** make him somewhat _stronger_ against it than most humans. It's like saying a human has no "special defense" against Green-K; yes, we're not "allergic" to it's radiation as he is, but a green K-bullet shot at us WILL hurt, though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't appear to have been any suggestion that Kryptonians would be any more resistant to magic under a red sun. I can find only one reference to magic on Krypton, in [Superman Vol 1 279](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_279). The linked reference doesn't give much detail, but even in the unlikely event that "Ca-Rox, a stage magician from old Krypton who actually had magical powers" used those powers to attack his fellow Kryptonians, it would have been difficult to gauge whether those attacks would have been more or less effective had those Kryptonians had been under a yellow sun.

Answer (score 2):

The Superman comics has not elaborated specifically about how supermans magic weakness works. The best i could find was a Pre-Crisis comic that tried to give an explanation. It claims that the reason is genetic and therefor has nothing to do with sunlight.

In [DC Comics Presents Vol 1 18](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/DC_Comics_Presents_Vol_1_18) the magic wielding super-heroine Zatanna tried to learn more about magic and its origin. She found a book that shed some light over the subject and has the following dialog with her father about it.

[image: DC Comics Presents Vol 1 18 page 7]
[image: DC Comics Presents Vol 1 18 page 8]

In short it claims that human beings has a small natural resistance to magic because of our relation to the race Homo Magus, which Zatanna belong to. Superman who comes from Krypton has no such relation and therefor no resistance at all.

If this explanation is still valid efter the Crisis is not known though.

Comment: I'd question the validity, because Krypton _did_ have a humanoid race that believed in magic at one time. and as a universal force, like light, heat, gravity or electricity, that "magical energy" should permeate the universe, including other species. so while Superman would possibly be be exempt from _earth_ magical defense [and there **is** an idea that magic is highly tied to the planet/place of its origin], that's not to say that Krypton was "devoid" of any form of magical connection. I mean, if the Thanagarians could have both science and magic, why not Krypton?

Comment: I think you are talking about the Wizards of Juru who were a race of  kryptonians that could use magic . But as far as i remember they only kept in the valley of Juru an did not breed with ordinary kryptonians to any degree.

Answer (score 1):

Superman himself has repeatedly said he has "no special defense" against magic, but this is... *questionable,* at best. "Special defense" meaning yes, he *is* vulnerable to it, and can be *affected* by it like other people... but due to some simple aspects of physics, and his physiology, his *natural defenses,* ---including durability, susceptibility and stamina against such attacks---- would likely *still* be somewhat above that of normal humans. Think of it this way...

To my knowledge, a "normal" human, has *no* invulnerability against lightning; there's a **very high** statistical probability that if one is struck by a certain amount of electricity...they will *die,* all things being even, correct? Well, Superman has shown on *several* occasions that he has *varied* responses to high dose voltages of electricity, from some physical pain [but **no injury**] at his weakest...

To it slowing him down a little, but him not being negatively impacted for more than a few seconds [go to **6:35** in the video to see him snapping off highly charged electrical wires]...

To him forming a circuit and **willingly letting it run through his body for nearly a full minute to power a massive machine** when necessary [**6:30**]

To him basically **outspeeding a lightning bolt** and **shrugging it off with NOT ONE ill effect!** [0:12-0:17]

Now keep in mind, the average, "normal" lightning bolt has a *massive* amount of power; typical lightning bolts contain **1 billion volts** of raw electrical charge and between 10,000 to 200,000 amperes of current. We just saw Supes shrug one of those off like "This ain't no thing." The human body has an inherently high resistance to electric current, so without sufficient *voltage,* a dangerous amount of current cannot flow through the body and cause injury or death. But, as a rough rule of thumb... at base, **fifty volts of electricity is sufficient enough** to drive a potentially lethal current through a human body.

Now granted, I don't have the exact voltage numbers for each example shown, and we *Are* dealing with different "versions" of the character....but merely by the visible presence of generated sparks in all of the videos above, we can presume that Supes tanked what could be scientifically estimated as roughly a **shit ton more than 50 volts** each time.... And he was *fine!*

*Now,* let's put Superman against Captain Marvel/Shazam... a magical hero **literally empowered** by Magic lightning from the *Greek Gods*.... and watch him take *multiple strikes to chest!* All that happens is that, yes, he is *in pain* for a bit...and his costume is ruined [3:22- 3:32...]

Now this is *magic lightning!* Even if we low-ball it and presume that it has roughly the same voltage as a *normal* bolt, due to its "magical" nature, it *should,*  by all accounts, either...

**[a]** completely bypass his powers/super dense molecular structure and thus kill him like any normal human being, at the high end, or

**[b]** hurt him *more* than normal lightning, at least, effectively causing *some* kind of physical injury

Judging from Superman's immediate condition afterwards though [no visible injuries, only costume was burned, no weakness], neither really seems to be the case.

I'm using these animated examples to show that, yes, Superman *is* somewhat more susceptible to magic... but it *does not* just "negate" his physical toughness or durability. As a regular Kryptonian, that "vulnerability to magic" **still** has to bypass some *very extraordinary* **physical and structural defenses,** which presumably are far, *faaaar* beyond the range of regular magic. Remember that magic, like any "power" requires a certain amount of energy, and *most* magic would generally be tailored to use on earth-bound mortals who *aren't* unnaturally strong, durable or in possession of an alien [re: non earth standard] energy absorption ability and healing factor.

Think of it this way...

Laws of physics state that in order for a body to be destroyed, a *greater force* than it can withstand must be applied to it. Another law [simplified] says that a body can withstand about as much force as it can put out. At his *weakest,* Superman has been shown to be able output *billions of tons of force* with his muscles *alone,* just to move or support buildings. And these are low-end feats for him. So logically, he should be able [and has been *shown* to] survive **giga-tons of force;** the guy takes that anytime he falls from space and smashes into the earth.

So unless specially tailored....like say, a mental attack, or a "Status affecting" spell, like "sleep for a year!", or a mystical poison of some kind... a "magical attack" would NEED to be able to *apply* an equivalent amount of force to *physically harm him.*

I'll make it even simpler....

A magical bullet, fired from an enchanted gun which is made to "always hit the target" it intends too *will* have an equal effect on both Superman, and a normal human. Neither of them has a "Special defense" against that kind of curse. However...it's still ***just** a measly bullet;* while the shots would likely *hit* both people, Superman, under most logic, would *not* take any *physical harm* from said bullet.  As a regular piece of earth metal fired at him, it simply **won't have the necessary force or density to do him any damage.**

You can see this principal at work in **Smallville** when Clark fights Lana, Chloe  and Lois, who are possessed by the spirits of three powerful dead witches. Earlier in the episode, they put a general spell on Clark and all the people at Chloe's birthday party, basically affecting them *mentally* and releasing their spirit of revelry. Just like all the others, Clark was affected. However, in *this* scene, Clark has found them out and they are using their magic against him in a battle. 
Even though Clark's powers are *still growing* at this stage,he basically "no sells" each shot; *everything* they throw at him with magic has a physical affect, yes, like pushing him to the ground...but it **doesn't hurt him!** The only way they can neutralize Clark is to apply the magic to him **specifically** and **directly...**

Same principal as the bullet; Clark is vulnerable to magic *Spells,* but magic *attacks* have *only* so much effect because the kid is just *too molecularly dense* to injure with normal earth items or regular amount of force, even with some potent magic behind it.

On the *other* hand, if the bullet was non lethal but cursed to make "anyone it hits completely change personalities," [technically a magical *spell*] well then that is something Superman's physical structure would *not* be able to defend against. Same with any spell that was made to effect him mentally, or change him in a way that warps reality. Anyone remember in  *Justice League Unlimited* when Wonder Woman was struck *directly* with Cersei's magic that turned her into a pig? Recall how her bracelets, which are **distinctly proof against all magic and force** remained untouched?

Same principle; a "transformation" spell may affect Superman, and even a magical *bladed* weapon which is made to cut flesh... but while a magical creature *would* be able to perhaps harm him, unless it was *Extremely powerful* or tailored **specifically** to bypass his abilities, it wouldn't likely be able to just outright "Destroy him".

The reason?

**His body has proven to be *highly* resistant to damage and physical harm, even against amounts of force which [on *this* planet] seem immense.**

I am theorizing that this extends to all *other* Kryptonians.

So yes, someone like Zataana can, say, "put a spell" on Superman or any other Kryptonian the same way she would a human. And depending on *how* that spell takes affect, they would see some kind of result. Turning them into an animal, for instance, or playing with their mind/soul, or making them clumsy... all of these *would* hit a Kryptonian much the same way they would hit a human.

Other types of spells, arguably, would be less effective though, simply because a normal Kryptonian's  **physical durability** would need *special magic, tailoring,* or at least *an enormous amount of raw power* to overcome. So, hitting them with magic lightning... making monsters to go after them.... trying to freeze or burn them to death.... all of *these* would require IMMENSE power to overcome a Kryptonian's natural base resistance to electricity, physical trauma, cold and heat [when under a yellow sun, I mean.]

There *is* a work around around this, however... a skilled magic user could simply use their powers to *strip the Kryptonian of their special abilities* making them, essentially, Human. That's what Lana and the girls did at the end of the scene, and Clark had to get his powers "jump started" by touching a Kryptonian artifact which trapped a massive amount of power in it. I'm not sure if the law of magic can *work* like that, because it would be a game breaker on any magical quest, and more evil spell casters would be doing it *all the time* in fiction. But even in the **Smallville** example, once a greater power [the Kryptonian crystal] was used, the earth-bound magic failed to have any more effect.

But it IS a possibility; magic users have used specific spells to "Seize" Superman's powers or "bring him down to normal" before.